# While loop won't stop

Tags: python, loops, type-conversion

```
while start_chapter<=end_chapter:
    os.makedirs("Chapter "+str(start_chapter))
    os.chdir("Chapter "+str(start_chapter))
    chap_url=link+"/c"+str(start_chapter)+"/"
    page=1
    try:
        max_page=get_max_page(chap_url)
    except:
        continue
    while(page<=max_page):
        page_url=chap_url+str(page)+".html"
        try:        
            pic_url=get_pic(page_url)
        except:
            break
        picture_shit=urllib2.urlopen(pic_url).read()
        with open(str(page)+"."+(pic_url.split(".")[len(pic_url.split("."))-1]), 'w') as f: f.write(picture_shit)
        print str(start_chapter)+"::"+str(page)
            page+=1
    os.chdir("../")
    start_chapter+=1
```

The inner while loop won't stop and I tested page and saw it was getting way over max_page which is 23 but it simply isn't stopping.Can anyone help with this?Thanks in advance...

Comment: page +=1 at the end of the while loop?

Comment: Well, considering neither of the loop variables change within the body of the loop, what would you expect?

Comment: sorry I copied the wrong code.Actually I had page+=1..Still it didn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`max_page` is a string, not a number.

```
>>> 1 < '0'
True
```

Comment: Right..Damn I didn't notice that...Thanks a lot man...I owe you one :D

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few issues here:

- You never increment `page` so it will never reach the value of `max_page` (edit: now fixed in your example)
- Following the above in your edit, the increment will only happen if the file is open successfully
- There is an intent error just below your `with` block
- `max_page` isn't a number which will cause issues as Ignacio points out
- The `try: continue:` block you have means that if there is an error assigning max_page, it won't be assigned again causing comparison issues

This should fix most of your issues:

```
while start_chapter<=end_chapter:
    os.makedirs("Chapter "+str(start_chapter))
    os.chdir("Chapter "+str(start_chapter))
    chap_url=link+"/c"+str(start_chapter)+"/"
    page=1
    try:
        max_page=int(get_max_page(chap_url))
        while(page<=max_page):
            page_url=chap_url+str(page)+".html"
            try:        
                pic_url=get_pic(page_url)
                picture_shit=urllib2.urlopen(pic_url).read()
                with open(str(page)+"."+(pic_url.split(".")[len(pic_url.split("."))-1]), 'w') as f:
                    f.write(picture_shit)
                print str(start_chapter)+"::"+str(page)
            except:
                break
            page+=1
    except:
        continue
    os.chdir("../")
    start_chapter+=1
```

Comment: No worries, is it working? If so as @Haidro suggested you should select an answer so people can find what worked for you in the future. StackOverflow isn't just for answering your question, its for answering the next persons question too :P

Comment: Well thanks it's working.Well to be honest the guy above you answered it right before so I had to select his answer by that tick mark..